# Unity3D: Cross Platform Video Streaming?

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-streaming, cross-platform, mp4, h.264

We are working on a prototyp application using unity3d. Your goal is to create a fluid and fun to use cross platform app.

The problem we facing right now is streaming (h.264 - mp4) video content over the web. This will be a major feature of our app.

I have already tried MovieTextures and the www class but it seems the files must be in ogg format which we can not provide. On the other hand handheld.playfullscreenmovie seems to be an android and ios only feature which uses the build in video player. This would be great if it would be supported on other platforms (e.g. Win8-Phone) as well.

Is there another cross platform option to stream (h.264 - mp4) video content over the web and display in full screen or as gui object? Or are there any plans to support something like this in the near future? Or is there a stable plugin for such a task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mp4 is not a streamable container. If you read the ISO specification, you will see that MP4 can not be streamed. This is because the MOOV atom can not be written until all frames are know and accounted for. This 100% incompatible for live video. There are supersets of MP4 used in DASH that make this possible. Essentially, they create a little mp4 (called a fragment) file every couple seconds. Alternatively you can use a container designed for streaming such as FLV or TS.

You will probably need to step outside the unity sdk a bit to enable this.

Comment: do you have the ISO at hand? I doubt that "mp4 cannot be streamed [because of the moov atom]" is true. I refer to this: http://fabiensanglard.net/mobile_progressive_playback/index.php

Comment: That is progressive playback of a pre-produced VOD. Is known as pseudo streaming. If you want the ISO spec, start with google.

Comment: Perhaps this answer needs an update because first of all MP4 files with moov before mdat exist (can't be written at once but obtained easily out of completed file). And then so called fragmented MP4 also exist. Both flavors even have (not so good but still) support in stock Media Foundation API in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

As of Unity 5 Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie supports Windows Phone and Windows Store as per http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html

---

On Windows Phone 8, Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie internally uses Microsoft Media Foundation for movie playback. On this platform, calling Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie with full or minimal control mode is not supported.

On Windows Store Apps and Windows Phone 8.1, Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie internally uses XAML MediaElement control.

On Windows Phone and Windows Store Apps, there generally isn't movie resolution or bitrate limit, however, higher resolution or bitrate movies will consume more memory for decoding. Weaker devices will also start skipping frames much sooner at extremely high resolutions. For example, Nokia Lumia 620 can only play videos smoothly up to 1920x1080. For these platforms, you can find list of supported formats here: Supported audio and video formats on Windows Store